# Debug the issue in my escape velocity program

Tags: java, replit

The assignment was to write a program which outputs

- planet's radius
- planet's mass
- escape velocity

The inputs are circumference and the acceleration.

With the 2 inputs, we were to use the

1. Circumference of a circle equation to calculate the radius,
2. Acceleration due to gravity equation to calculate the mass
3. Escape velocity formula to calculate the escape velocity.

If my inputs are 40075 (circumference of the earth), and 9.8 (acceleration), my output radius is 6378 (correct), output mass is 5.97e18 (correct output should be 5.97e24), my output escape velocity is 354 (correct output is 11184).

---

Here are the assignment instructions.

"USING THE TWO EQUATIONS BELOW (one given and one in the link)

```
equation 1:
a=(G*m)/(r^2)
```

and

equation 2: refer link below

http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/escape_velocity_formula/90/

G is a constant (find it)

Ask the user for the circumference in km

Ask for the the acceleration due to gravity in m/s^2

Output:

1. Planet radius in km
2. Planet mass in kg (using equation 1)
3. Escape Velocity in km/s (using equation 2)

Include units and formatting"

Here is my code for the program.

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("\nWelcome to the Escape Velocity Application. To begin, please enter the following information below. \nEnter the circumference (km):");
    double circum = userInput.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2):");
    double a = userInput.nextDouble();

    //Gravitational constant 
    double G = 6.67408e-11;

    //Radius
    double r = Math.round((circum/2)/Math.PI);

    //Mass
    double m = Math.round((a*(Math.pow(r,2)))/G);

    //Escape Velocity
    double e = Math.round(Math.sqrt((2*G*m)/r));

    System.out.println("\nThe radius is: "+r+" kilometers.");
    System.out.println("\nThe mass is: "+m+" kg.");
    System.out.println("\nThe escape velocity is: "+e+" m/s.");

  }
}
```

Comment: `double r = Math.round((circum/2)/Math.PI);` should be `double r = Math.round((circum/2.0)/Math.PI);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic physics error! When you use any formulas in physics make sure you are using the correct units.

You can accept the input for the circumference of the celestial body in km but make sure you convert it to meters during calculation. Remember : `x km = x *10^3m`

```
double circum = 40075 * Math.pow(10, 3); // convert km to m

double f = 9.807; //more accurate

double G = 6.67408e-11;

double r = circum/(2*Math.PI);

double m = f*Math.pow(r, 2)/G;

double e = (Math.sqrt((2.0*G*(m))/r));

System.out.println("The radius is: " + r * Math.pow(10, -3) + " kilometers.");
System.out.println("The mass is: " + m + " kg.");
System.out.println("The escape velocity is: " + e + " m/s.");
```

This code gives the output:

```
The radius is: 6378.134344407706 kilometers.

The mass is: 5.981328662579845E24 kg.

The escape velocity is: 11184.843630163667 m/s.
```

All I have changed is converting the km to m and changing f to a more accurate value. Also remember not to round until your final calculation is done, this maintains the greatest possible accuracy.

Comment: Thank you! This helped very much. I took your advice and modified it with my current code and it works!

Comment: That's great to hear! @BipoN Glad I could be of assistance :)